# Python: How to pass dynamic variables into XML?

Tags: python, xml, api, xml-parsing

I’m working with the USPS APIs which are XMLs. I want to be able to pass variables into the XML tree without rebuilding it child by child. How do I do it in Python?

```
def fixed_xml_body_as_string(dest_zip, origin_zip):
  
  #pass zip codes into XML

  return """
  https://secure.shippingapis.com/shippingapi.dll?API=RateV4&XML=
  <RateV4Request USERID='XXXXXXXXXXX'>
  <Revision>2</Revision>
  <Package ID="1ST">
  <Service>PRIORITY</Service>
  <ZipOrigination></ZipOrigination>
  <ZipDestination></ZipDestination>
  <Pounds>1</Pounds>
  <Ounces>0</Ounces>
  <Container></Container>
  <Width></Width>
  <Length></Length>
  <Height></Height>
  <Girth></Girth>
  <Machinable>false</Machinable>
  </Package>
  </RateV4Request>
"""
```

I want to dynamically pass the zip codes into the XML.

Comment: Adding code to the body. USPS has a few APIs to track shipping, get rates..etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string format like the below (Note that your 'xml' is not a valid one)

```
def fixed_xml_body_as_string(dest_zip, origin_zip):
    # pass zip codes into XML

    return f"""
  https://secure.shippingapis.com/shippingapi.dll?API=RateV4&XML=
  <RateV4Request USERID='XXXXXXXXXXX'>
  <Revision>2</Revision>
  <Package ID="1ST">
  <Service>PRIORITY</Service>
  <ZipOrigination>{origin_zip}</ZipOrigination>
  <ZipDestination>{dest_zip}</ZipDestination>
  <Pounds>1</Pounds>
  <Ounces>0</Ounces>
  <Container></Container>
  <Width></Width>
  <Length></Length>
  <Height></Height>
  <Girth></Girth>
  <Machinable>false</Machinable>
  </Package>
  </RateV4Request>
"""


print(fixed_xml_body_as_string(23, 99))
```

output

```
 https://secure.shippingapis.com/shippingapi.dll?API=RateV4&XML=
  <RateV4Request USERID='XXXXXXXXXXX'>
  <Revision>2</Revision>
  <Package ID="1ST">
  <Service>PRIORITY</Service>
  <ZipOrigination>99</ZipOrigination>
  <ZipDestination>23</ZipDestination>
  <Pounds>1</Pounds>
  <Ounces>0</Ounces>
  <Container></Container>
  <Width></Width>
  <Length></Length>
  <Height></Height>
  <Girth></Girth>
  <Machinable>false</Machinable>
  </Package>
  </RateV4Request>
```